# Laravel Eloquent add a prefix to an attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with names of districts in my country. Is there a good and easy way to add 'District' string before every name?

There is my table structure:

```
+------------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | Sofia             |
+----+-------------------+
| 2  | Shumen            |
+----+-------------------+
| 3  | Varna             |
+------------------------+
```

I need when I call District::find(1)->name to get 'District Shumen'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) for that. In your model:

```
public function getNameAttribute(){
    return 'District ' . $this->attributes['name'];
}
```